# What are the public transport options to Johnson Space Center from Houston Downtown?

Tags: public-transport, geek-travel, houston

I'll be spending a couple days in downtown Houston, and would not miss a trip to Johnson Space Center for the world. However, it is quite far outside the city, and I was wondering what are the public transport options to Johnson Space Center from Houston Downtown.

Comment: Do you have a driving license, could you rent a car?

Comment: I just reached out to Avis in Houston, and it seems like a French driver's licence and a credit card is all you need.

I'd say yes then!

Comment: Hi and welcome. I tried to reformulate the question to render it less opinion-based. A question asking for the "best" is unfortunately unanswerable since we all have different opinions on what "best" means.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean **Space Center Houston**, the Johnson Space Center visitor complex, you can talk Metro Bus 246 or 249 from downtown directly to Space Center Houston.

Schedules here: [Bus Schedules](http://www.ridemetro.org/Pages/BusSched.aspx)

Comment: Route 249 also offers service to Johnson Space Center. (In fact, given their respective schedules, a tourist coming from downtown would almost certainly take Route 249 to the Space Center.)  Note also that neither route operates on Saturdays or Sundays.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is taking a while, but the bus fare is so low, I think it is a very good option.